# Covariant derivative of product of arcs in Lie group

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Given a Lie group $G$ and two arcs $\alpha$ and $\beta$, I understand the product rule for the differentiation: $$\frac{d}{dt}(\alpha\cdot\beta)(t) = dL_{\alpha(t)}\cdot\beta'(t) + dR_{\beta (t)}\cdot\alpha'(t)$$

Given some left invariant metric (or biinvariant, if necessary, though I would prefer the more general case), I would like to compute the covariant derivative of this product, i.e. $\frac{\nabla}{dt}\frac{d}{dt}(\alpha\cdot\beta)$.

Of course $\nabla$ is invariant under left multiplication, but $dL_{\alpha(t)}$ depends on $t$, so I can't just move it in front of the derivative.

In my special situation, $\alpha(t) = \exp_L(tv)$ and $\beta(t)=\exp_L(x(t))$, where $x$ is a curve in $T_eG$.

Is it possible to compute the covariant derivative?